# VUE.JS template not showing up

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-echo, redis-server, npm-audit

I have created a template for chat module. It was working fine yesterday but today there were some issues in some npm module so I ran the command `npm audit fix --force` and after that command is finished my chat template or any VUE template stops working means it is not showing up.
Here is the code of my template.

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Chat with {{ withUser.name }}

                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm pull-right" @click="startVideoCallToUser(withUser.id)" type="button">
                        <span class="fa fa-video-camera"></span> Video Call
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="chat" v-chat-scroll>
                        <li class="clearfix" v-for="message in messages" v-bind:class="{ 'right' : check(message.sender.id), 'left' : !check(message.sender.id) }">
                        <span class="chat-img" v-bind:class="{ 'pull-right' : check(message.sender.id) , 'pull-left' : !check(message.sender.id) }">
                            <img :src="'http://placehold.it/50/FA6F57/fff&text='+ message.sender.name" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
                        </span>
                            <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                                <div class="header">
                                    <small class=" text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span><timeago :since="message.created_at" :auto-update="10"></timeago></small>
                                    <strong v-bind:class="{ 'pull-right' : check(message.sender.id) , 'pull-left' : !check(message.sender.id)}" class="primary-font">
                                        {{ message.sender.name }}
                                    </strong>
                                </div>
                                <p v-bind:class="{ 'pull-right' : check(message.sender.id) , 'pull-left' : !check(message.sender.id)}">
                                    {{ message.text }}
                                </p>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3" v-for="file in message.files">
                                        <img :src="file.file_details.webPath" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                        <a :href="file.file_details.webPath" target="_blank" download>Download - {{ file.name }}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="btn-input" type="text" v-model="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" type="button" @click.prevent="send()" id="btn-chat">
                            Send
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="file" multiple class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" type="button" @click.prevent="sendFiles()">
                            Send Files
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-center">
            <video-section></video-section>
        </div>

        <div id="incomingVideoCallModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Incoming Call</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="answerCallButton" class="btn btn-success">Answer</button>
                        <button type="button" id="denyCallButton" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Deny</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="file in conversation.files">
            <img :src="file.file_details.webPath" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <a :href="file.file_details.webPath" target="_blank" download>Download - {{ file.name }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>

$(function () {
    var localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
    var remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
    var answerButton = document.getElementById('answerCallButton');

    answerButton.onclick = answerCall;

    $('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);
});

var files;

var conversationID;
var luid;
var ruid;
var startTime;
var localStream;
var pc;
var offerOptions = {
    offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
    offerToReceiveVideo: 1
};
var isCaller = false;
var peerConnectionDidCreate = false;
var candidateDidReceived = false;

export default {
    props: ['conversation' , 'currentUser'],
    data() {
        return {
            conversationId : this.conversation.conversationId,
            channel : this.conversation.channel_name,
            messages : this.conversation.messages,
            withUser : this.conversation.user,
            text : '',
            constraints : {
                audio: false,
                video: true
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        startVideoCallToUser (id) {

            Cookies.set('remoteUUID', id);

            window.remoteUUID = id;

            luid = Cookies.get('uuid');
            ruid = Cookies.get('remoteUUID');
            isCaller = true;

            start()
        },
        check(id) {
            return id === this.currentUser.id;
        },
        send() {
            var self = this;
            axios.post('/chat/message/send',{
                conversationId : this.conversationId,
                text: this.text,
            }).then((response) => {
                this.listenForNewMessage();
                self.text = '';
            });
        },
        sendFiles() {
            var data = new FormData();

            $.each(files, function(key, value)
            {
                data.append('files[]', value);
            });

            data.append('conversationId' , this.conversationId);

            axios.post('/chat/message/send/file', data);
        },
        listenForNewMessage: function () {

            Echo.join(this.channel)
                .here((users) => {
                    console.log(users)
                })
                .listen('\\PhpJunior\\LaravelVideoChat\\Events\\NewConversationMessage', (data) => {
                    var self = this;
                    if ( data.files.length > 0 ){
                        $.each( data.files , function( key, value ) {
                            self.conversation.files.push(value);
                        });
                    }
                    this.messages.push(data);
                })
                .listen('\\PhpJunior\\LaravelVideoChat\\Events\\VideoChatStart', (data) => {

                    if(data.to != this.currentUser.id){
                        return;
                    }

                    if(data.type === 'signal'){
                        onSignalMessage(data);
                    }else if(data.type === 'text'){
                        console.log('received text message from ' + data.from + ', content: ' + data.content);
                    }else{
                        console.log('received unknown message type ' + data.type + ' from ' + data.from);
                    }
                });
        },
    },
    beforeMount () {
        Cookies.set('uuid', this.currentUser.id);
        Cookies.set('conversationID', this.conversationId);
    },
    mounted() {
        this.listenForNewMessage();
    }
}

function onSignalMessage(m){
    console.log(m.subtype);
    if(m.subtype === 'offer'){
        console.log('got remote offer from ' + m.from + ', content ' + m.content);
        Cookies.set('remoteUUID', m.from);
        onSignalOffer(m.content);
    }else if(m.subtype === 'answer'){
        onSignalAnswer(m.content);
    }else if(m.subtype === 'candidate'){
        onSignalCandidate(m.content);
    }else if(m.subtype === 'close'){
        onSignalClose();
    }else{
        console.log('unknown signal type ' + m.subtype);
    }
}

function onSignalClose() {
    trace('Ending call');
    pc.close();
    pc = null;

    closeMedia();
    clearView();
}

function closeMedia(){
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track){track.stop();});
}

function clearView(){
    localVideo.srcObject = null;
    remoteVideo.srcObject = null;
}

function onSignalCandidate(candidate){
    onRemoteIceCandidate(candidate);
}

function onRemoteIceCandidate(candidate){
    trace('onRemoteIceCandidate : ' + candidate);
    if(peerConnectionDidCreate){
        addRemoteCandidate(candidate);
    }else{
        //remoteCandidates.push(candidate);
        var candidates = Cookies.getJSON('candidate');
        if(candidateDidReceived){
            candidates.push(candidate);
        }else{
            candidates = [candidate];
            candidateDidReceived = true;
        }
        Cookies.set('candidate', candidates);
    }
}

function onSignalAnswer(answer){
    onRemoteAnswer(answer);
}

function onRemoteAnswer(answer){
    trace('onRemoteAnswer : ' + answer);
    pc.setRemoteDescription(answer).then(function(){onSetRemoteSuccess(pc)}, onSetSessionDescriptionError);
}

function onSignalOffer(offer){
    Cookies.set('offer', offer);
    $('#incomingVideoCallModal').modal('show');
}

function answerCall() {
    isCaller = false;
    luid = Cookies.get('uuid');
    ruid = Cookies.get('remoteUUID');
    $('#incomingVideoCallModal').modal('hide');
    start()
}

function gotStream(stream) {
    trace('Received local stream');
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    localStream = stream;
    call()
}

function start() {

    trace('Requesting local stream');

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: {
            width: {
                exact: 320
            },
            height: {
                exact: 240
            }
        }
    })
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(function(e) {
        alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
    });
}

function call() {
    conversationID = Cookies.get('conversationID');

    trace('Starting call');
    startTime = window.performance.now();
    var videoTracks = localStream.getVideoTracks();
    var audioTracks = localStream.getAudioTracks();
    if (videoTracks.length > 0) {
        trace('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
    }
    if (audioTracks.length > 0) {
        trace('Using audio device: ' + audioTracks[0].label);
    }

    var configuration = { "iceServers": [{ "urls": "stun:stun.ideasip.com" }] };
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    trace('Created local peer connection object pc');

    pc.onicecandidate = function(e) {
        onIceCandidate(pc, e);
    };

    pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(e) {
        onIceStateChange(pc, e);
    };

    pc.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;

    pc.addStream(localStream);

    trace('Added local stream to pc');

    peerConnectionDidCreate = true;

    if(isCaller) {
        trace(' createOffer start');
        trace('pc createOffer start');

        pc.createOffer(
            offerOptions
        ).then(
            onCreateOfferSuccess,
            onCreateSessionDescriptionError
        );
    }else{
        onAnswer()
    }
}

function onAnswer(){
    var remoteOffer = Cookies.getJSON('offer');

    pc.setRemoteDescription(remoteOffer).then(function(){onSetRemoteSuccess(pc)}, onSetSessionDescriptionError);

    pc.createAnswer().then(
        onCreateAnswerSuccess,
        onCreateSessionDescriptionError
    );
}

function onCreateAnswerSuccess(desc) {
    trace('Answer from pc:\n' + desc.sdp);
    trace('pc setLocalDescription start');
    pc.setLocalDescription(desc).then(
        function() {
            onSetLocalSuccess(pc);
        },
        onSetSessionDescriptionError
    );
    conversationID = Cookies.get('conversationID');
    var message = {from: luid, to:ruid, type: 'signal', subtype: 'answer', content: desc, time:new Date()};
    axios.post('/trigger/' + conversationID , message );
}

function onSetRemoteSuccess(pc) {
    trace(pc + ' setRemoteDescription complete');
    applyRemoteCandidates();
}

function applyRemoteCandidates(){
    var candidates = Cookies.getJSON('candidate');
    for(var candidate in candidates){
        addRemoteCandidate(candidates[candidate]);
    }
    Cookies.remove('candidate');
}

function addRemoteCandidate(candidate){
    pc.addIceCandidate(candidate).then(
        function() {
            onAddIceCandidateSuccess(pc);
        },
        function(err) {
            onAddIceCandidateError(pc, err);
        });
}

function onIceCandidate(pc, event) {
    if (event.candidate){
        trace(pc + ' ICE candidate: \n' + (event.candidate ? event.candidate.candidate : '(null)'));
        conversationID = Cookies.get('conversationID');
        var message = {from: luid, to:ruid, type: 'signal', subtype: 'candidate', content: event.candidate, time:new Date()};
        axios.post('/trigger/' + conversationID , message );
    }
}

function onAddIceCandidateSuccess(pc) {
    trace(pc + ' addIceCandidate success');
}

function onAddIceCandidateError(pc, error) {
    trace(pc + ' failed to add ICE Candidate: ' + error.toString());
}

function onIceStateChange(pc, event) {
    if (pc) {
        trace(pc + ' ICE state: ' + pc.iceConnectionState);
        console.log('ICE state change event: ', event);
    }
}

function onCreateSessionDescriptionError(error) {
    trace('Failed to create session description: ' + error.toString());
}

function onCreateOfferSuccess(desc) {
    trace('Offer from pc\n' + desc.sdp);
    trace('pc setLocalDescription start');
    pc.setLocalDescription(desc).then(
        function() {
            onSetLocalSuccess(pc);
        },
        onSetSessionDescriptionError
    );

    conversationID = Cookies.get('conversationID');
    var message = {from: luid, to:ruid, type: 'signal', subtype: 'offer', content: desc, time:new Date()};
    axios.post('/trigger/' + conversationID , message );
}

function onSetLocalSuccess(pc) {
    trace( pc + ' setLocalDescription complete');
}

function onSetSessionDescriptionError(error) {
    trace('Failed to set session description: ' + error.toString());
}

function gotRemoteStream(e) {
    if (remoteVideo.srcObject !== e.stream) {
        remoteVideo.srcObject = e.stream;
        trace('pc received remote stream');
    }
}

function trace(arg) {
    var now = (window.performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3);
    console.log(now + ': ', arg);
}

function prepareUpload(event)
{
    files = event.target.files;
}
 </script>

<style>
 .chat
 {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

.chat li
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #B3A9A9;
}

.chat li.left .chat-body
{
    margin-left: 60px;
}

.chat li.right .chat-body
{
    margin-right: 60px;
}


.chat li .chat-body p
{
    margin: 0;
    color: #777777;
}

.panel .slidedown .glyphicon, .chat .glyphicon
{
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.panel-body
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 250px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #555;
}
```

And This is how I am calling my template in my blade template.

```
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <chat-room :conversation="{{ $conversation }}" :current-user="{{ auth()->user() }}"></chat-room>
</div>
 @endsection
```

There are no errors in my laravel-echo-server nor in redis server nor in npm but still it is not showing up. I have tried some solutions but none of them are working.

Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in Chrome dev tools for Javascript errors?